# In R, how can I adjust the number of significant digits in stat_pvalue_manual()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The function `stat_pvalue_manual()` will add p-values to boxplots using `ggboxplot`. However, the p-values that are printed are sometimes many digits long. I would like to limit the number of decimal places to 3. How can I do that?

From the plot below you will see that the p-value for versicolor and virginica is 5 decimal places, how can I adjust the code below to report back 3 decimal places (i.e., 0.009)?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)
library(ggpubr)

test <- iris
test$Species <- as.factor(test$Species)
test.aov <- test %>% anova_test(Sepal.Width ~ Species)
test.tukey <- test %>% tukey_hsd(Sepal.Width ~ Species)
test.tukey <- test.tukey %>% add_xy_position(x = "Species")

ggboxplot(test, x = "Species", y = "Sepal.Width", outlier.shape = NA) +
  stat_pvalue_manual(test.tukey, hide.ns = TRUE, y.position = c(5,4.5,4), label = "p = {p.adj}") +
  geom_jitter(shape=16, alpha = 0.4, size = 2, position=position_jitter(0.1)) +
  labs(subtitle = get_test_label(test.aov, detailed = T)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,5,1), limits = c(0,5)) +
  xlab("Species") +
  ylab("Sepal Length") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(vjust = -105, hjust = 0.05),
        text = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"))
```

Comment: Your can modify the format of `p.adj` in the `test.tukey` data frame: `test.tukey <- test.tukey %>% add_xy_position(x = "Species") %>% mutate(p.adj={scales::pvalue(p.adj)})`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use`label = "p = {scales::pvalue(p.adj)}"`

```r
ggboxplot(test, x = "Species", y = "Sepal.Width", outlier.shape = NA) +
  stat_pvalue_manual(test.tukey, hide.ns = TRUE, y.position = c(5,4.5,4), 
                     label = "p = {scales::pvalue(p.adj)}") +
  geom_jitter(shape=16, alpha = 0.4, size = 2, position=position_jitter(0.1)) +
  labs(subtitle = get_test_label(test.aov, detailed = T)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,5,1), limits = c(0,5)) +
  xlab("Species") +
  ylab("Sepal Length") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(vjust = -105, hjust = 0.05),
        text = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"))
```

[image]